# Opacity issue in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency

I made an image in Illustrator with the pen tool and stuff and now it's kinda transparent. When I click the opacity however, it says that it's 100% on both the layer and the path. I have other layers that look perfectly fine, and if I multiply this layer then the opacity increases. I'm not sure what the problem is.

Transparency window and appearance windows say 100%. Also, I discovered that when I take a path from the layer and put it on a different layer, the opacity works fine.

Here's a capture:

[image]

You will see 2 objects and a lion cartoon, the lion cartoon was imported from google chrome, so the orange object on the right is on the lions layer, and the orange object on the left is on the layer where I created it. Hope the picture explains something XD

Comment: Are you sure you mean you made a vector and not an image?  Reason why I ask, images are typically raster based and Illustrator is a vector based program.  Do you mind posting an example because I would like to know what you are doing.

Comment: "with pen tool and stuff..." is pretty non-descriptive. Check if there's an opacity setting in the Appearance Panel with the object selected.

Comment: Select one of the 'kinda transparent' objects and, in the Transparency window or in the Appearance window, make sure the blending mode (drop-down menu) is set to 'Normal'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are multiple ways to change the opacity of an object.

1) Change the opacity of the entire layer. This is not your problem, since you're already stated that it's at 100%.

2) Change the opacity of the path. Also not your problem, as you've stated.

3) **Change the opacity specifically for the stroke or fill.** This may be your problem. In the appearance panel, click the expand arrow to the left of the stroke and fill effects and ensure opacity is set to 100%.

Answer (score 1):

In the options panel in the Appearance window, try "Reduce to Basic Appearance" this was what I had to do when working through some tricky buried transparency effects from an svg file I imported.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a file with a transparency problem. The transparency panel showed 100%. First I opened the Appearance panel, and selected the Hamburger menu and then selected Clear Appearance. When I went back to the Transparency panel it showed the image at 50% and I was able to change the transparency.

Answer (score 0):

Just ungroup the objects. Then is will show the accurate opacity setting and you can set it to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem, and for me it was just a layer problem. The object with the unwanted transparency was on the wrong layer.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a few years late to this question, but I was also having problems with my opacity on certain elements within my AI file that would randomly change opacity, even after saving the file down with everything displayed as it should and also making sure each individual element (ungrouped) was at 100% opacity. Every time I reopened this file after saving, the opacity would be skewed again and I would have to re-isolate each translucent element to reset it back to 100% again, then the cycle would continue every time I closed and reopened my file.

The solution that worked for me was what was mentioned earlier in this forum. I had to select either the "Appearance" option in the windows tab, or go to the properties tab where opacity is found and click the ellipsis (...) in the bottom right corner of that box. The second option is a bit faster. Then I clicked the "clear appearance" button to reset my display back to the opacity's default setting. For some reason, the bigger my file got, no matter how I saved it down, the opacity on certain objects would become corrupt and change the default opacity setting to 10% for me. Now I know what fixes this though and I hope this helps anyone else who experienced the same problem that I did.